# SQL Server : after using GROUP BY with CASE, the ORDER BY doesn't work

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Consider the following T-SQL query. I'm using `CASE` in the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` to combine the records of two persons into one because it's really the same person. I've changed the names to just 'PersonX' for this example.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT d.PONum) AS POCount, 
    ISNULL(SUM(d.DocExtCost), 0) AS POValue, 
    CASE v.Buyer_c          
       WHEN 'Person5' 
          THEN 'Person4'    
          ELSE v.Buyer_c                    
    END AS BuyerID
FROM 
    [Dbo].PODetail AS d       
INNER JOIN 
    [Dbo].Vendor AS v ON (d.Company = v.Company AND d.VendorNum = v.VendorNum)
WHERE 
    v.Buyer_c IN ('Person1', 'Person2', 'Person3', 'Person4', 'Person5')
GROUP BY 
    CASE v.Buyer_c 
       WHEN 'Person5' 
          THEN 'Person4'    
          ELSE v.Buyer_c 
    END
ORDER BY 
    v.Buyer_c   <-- This order by doesn't work
```

Results without the order by:

[image]

When I try to use the order by I get this error:

> Column "Dbo.Vendor.Buyer_c" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I don't know where to add the `v.Buyer_c`, it's already in the `GROUP BY` clause in the `CASE` statement. If I add it again it by itself like this:

```
GROUP BY 
    CASE v.Buyer_c 
       WHEN 'Person5' 
          THEN 'Person4'    
          ELSE v.Buyer_c 
    END, 
    v.Buyer_c
```

it stops grouping correctly and gives two different records for Person4 & Person5.

I want to use the order by so I can order the records alphabetically. How can I order the records alphabetically with the buyerID?

Comment: Use the column alias `ORDER BY BuyerID`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you put `order by BuyerID` and check

Comment: This worked! I swear I tried to do that before. Thank you, I knew it was probably something simple.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the same logic as order by

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT d.PONum) AS POCount, 
   ISNULL(SUM(d.DocExtCost), 0) AS POValue, 
   CASE v.Buyer_c           
        WHEN 'Person5' THEN 'Person4'   
        ELSE v.Buyer_c                  
   END AS BuyerID

FROM [Dbo].PODetail AS d       

INNER JOIN [Dbo].Vendor AS v
    ON (d.Company = v.Company AND
        d.VendorNum = v.VendorNum)

WHERE v.Buyer_c IN ('Person1', 'Person2', 'Person3', 'Person4', 'Person5')

GROUP BY CASE v.Buyer_c 
        WHEN 'Person5' THEN 'Person4'   
        ELSE v.Buyer_c 
     END

ORDER BY CASE v.Buyer_c 
        WHEN 'Person5' THEN 'Person4'   
        ELSE v.Buyer_c 
     END
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be one way of doing it:

```
with cte as 
(
    select count(distinct d.ponum) as pocount, 
        isnull(sum(d.docextcost), 0) as povalue, 
        case v.buyer_c           
            when 'person5' then 'person4'   
            else v.buyer_c                  
        end as buyerid
    from [dbo].podetail as d       
    inner join [dbo].vendor as v on (d.company = v.company and d.vendornum = v.vendornum)
    where v.buyer_c in ('person1', 'person2', 'person3', 'person4', 'person5')      
    group by case v.buyer_c 
            when 'person5' then 'person4'   
            else v.buyer_c 
            end
)
select *
from cte
order by buyerid
```